# Cassandra Upgrade limitations

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

We are upgrading from DSE 4.5 to DSE 4.8.9 in 10 node PRODUCTION cluster.
We have daily batch jobs running in our application which  bulk load the data in the cluster , some jobs TRUNCATE the tables and load fresh data and some loader jobs which continuously insert the data.

Consider these scenarios :

Case 1 :
Let say my one node has DSE 4.8 installed but upgradesstables is running .
All nodes are online at this moment and 2 different schema exist (9 nodes on dse4.5 and 1 node on dse4.8.9).
In this case , will TRUNCATE work ?

Case 2:
One of my nodes is fully upgraded to DSE 4.8 , which makes my cluster to be in partially upgraded state, all nodes online,2 schema exists (9 nodes on DSE 4.5 and 1 node on DSE 4.8).

Will TRUNCATE work in this case ?

Please suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a practice to upgrade the binaries first on all the nodes so that we have one schema across the cluster .
Avoid the use of TRUNCATE till all nodes have completed running "upgradesstables".

Comment given by markc is also to be noted :

Do not enable new features.

Do not run nodetool repair.

Do not issue these types of CQL queries during a rolling restart: DDL and TRUNCATE.

During upgrades, the nodes on different versions might show a schema disagreement.

Failure to upgrade SSTables when required results in a significant performance impact and increased disk usage. Upgrading is not complete until the SSTables are upgraded.

Answer (score 3):

Its not recommended to issue a `TRUNCATE` command during an upgrade, this is one of the limitations outlined [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-upgrade/upgrade/cassandra/upgrdCassandraDetails.html)

To quote the link:

> Do not enable new features.
>
> Do not run nodetool repair.
>
> Do not issue these types of CQL queries during a rolling restart: DDL
>   and TRUNCATE.
>
> During upgrades, the nodes on different versions might show a schema
>   disagreement.
>
> Failure to upgrade SSTables when required results in a significant
>   performance impact and increased disk usage. Upgrading is not complete
>   until the SSTables are upgraded.